# Sequelize - sequelize.sync()

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i don't understand how it work the istruction `sequelize.sync()`.
This is an example:

Into my server.js file:

```
db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {

app.listen(PORT);
console.log("Express listen on  port: " + PORT);
})
```

And into my db.js file for create a new database:

```
//create a sequelize database for export it into server.js

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(undefined, undefined, undefined, {
    'dialect': 'sqlite',
    'storage': __dirname + '/data/dev-todo-api.sqlite' // location where you create a new sqlite database 
});

var db = {};

db.todo = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/models/todo.js"); 
db.sequelize = sequelize; //contain a settings of database
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

And into `__dirname + "/models/todo.js"` i have created my tables/models. Into server.js when i launch `db.sequelize.sync()`, how do it to know that my models must be stored into database? I never call `db.todo` ( only for create a models )

Thank you very much
Morris

Answer (score -1):

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(undefined, undefined, undefined, {
    'dialect': 'sqlite',
    'storage': __dirname + '/data/dev-todo-api.sqlite' // location where you create a new sqlite database 
});

var db = {};

db.todo = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/models/todo.js");

db.sequelize = sequelize; //contain a settings of database
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync().done(); // Use here

module.exports = db;
```